# Making a command to open *.h files with vim with separate tabs in the terminal

Tags: linux, bash, vim, terminal

How can I write a command that will open multiple files, given by argument, in Vim, giving each Vim instance (and corresponding file) its own tab in the terminal?

I tried doing this, but xfce4-terminal is having problems with loading 256 colors (it keeps going to 8 even when `TERM == xterm-256color`):

```
vims ()
{
        for f; do xfce4-terminal --tab --hold --execute vim $f
        done
}
```

Comment: You need, or already have in your actual code, a semicolon before the `do`.  You don't need the other three semicolons.

Comment: Why don't you simply open every file in a single Vim instance?

Comment: I prefer to have separate terminal windows/tabs, it just seems better to navigate through tabs on my terminal than via vim.

Comment: Obligatory learn to love buffers. You may want to look at using the arglist. See `:h arglist` and [Meet the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist/)

Comment: Are you able to automatically separate all buffers into vim tabs?

Comment: What about opening each file in a separate Vim tab? If that's an option there are some possibilities...

Answer (score 0):

How about using tmux within a single terminal window?  It makes this sort of automation much easier.

You can start a new session with:

```
tmux new-session -s vims -n vim0 -d "ls $@"
```

and then spawn as many tabs as you like:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    tmux new-window -t vims -d -n "$f" "vim $f"
done
```

Plus you get lots of other fun benefits from tmux.  You can leave your vim in mid-insert and ssh in and `tmux attach` to pick up at exactly the same point.

Answer (score 0):

I know you were specifically asking about a terminal tab per file, but the following shell script will open each file given it as an argument in a separate *Vim* tab. See `:he tabedit` in Vim for more details.

```
#!/bin/sh

################################################################################
#   vim_tabs.sh
#   Open a bunch of files in separate terminal Vim tabs
################################################################################
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "No files to open..."
    exit 1
fi

vim_cmd="vim $1"
shift

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    vim_cmd="$vim_cmd -c \":tabnew $1\""
    shift
done

echo "$vim_cmd"
eval "$vim_cmd"
```

Then you can execute this by doing `./vim_tabs.sh "$(ls *.h)"`.